# jQuery image gallery not preloading?

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-gallery, preloader

I have a basic image gallery which is supposed to display a GIF and a white background when loading. For some reason this isn't showing...

Any ideas why? Heres the link http://v3.edharrisondesign.com/about/

Answer (score 0):

in your `nivo-slider.css`you have to add this line. That should work

```
.nivoSlider {
   background:url("/stylesheets/default/loading.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50%;
}
```

and remove that line from `default.css`

```
.theme-default .nivoSlider {
   background: url("loading.gif") no-repeat scroll 50% 50% #FFFFFF; // this line
   margin-bottom: 10px;
   position: relative;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I thought you had nailed it but I made the changes and still no luck. Have no idea where I've gone wrong...

Comment: well, you may try changing `$(window).load(function() {

    $('#slider').nivoSlider();

});` to `$(document).ready(function() {

    $('#slider').nivoSlider();
});`

Comment: Hmm gave it a go but no joy. I have a feeling the script is right but I'm making a silly mistake somewhere